# How to set First broker login to Keycloak token exchanging client?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, idp, token-exchange

I have a Keycloak client that exchange Google access token to Keycloak token via http request to `/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token`. This client linked to Google idp, but by default uses other authentication flow. When the token is exchanged for the first time, a new user is also registered. I need to apply custom First broker login to register a new user or special SPI on this client.

I can't find in console where i can do it. Is it possible?

Comment: I created a custom extension using "IdpCreateUserIfUniqueAuthenticator" class as base.
In the Authentication page I create a new "First Broker Login" adding the new "Execution".
In the "Identity Provider" I use this flow.
I don't know if is possible to use a "Authentication Flow Overrides" in the client together with Identity Providers "First Login Flow"

Comment: Please provide more details on what first login flow should do. In general, you can create custom first login flows via the keycloak administration interface. Navigate to "Authentication" in the side-bar. Create your own custom flow and select it in the IDP settings "first login-flow".